# Equivalent definition of nilpotency for infinite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, infinite-groups, nilpotent-groups

> Let $G$ be a finite group. TFAE:
>
> (1) $G$ is nilpotent.
>
> (2) $N_{G}(H) > H$ for all subgroups $H< G$.
>
> (3) Every maximal subgroup of $G$ is a normal subgroup.

The proof of these equivalences seems to imply that $(1) \Rightarrow (2) \Rightarrow (3)$ holds for infinite groups as well. I was wondering if $(2)$ and/or $(3)$ are also equivalent with $(1)$ for infinite groups. I would have to work with nonabelian infinite nilpotent groups, but to be honest, I don't know any, which in addition would make thinking about normalizers and maximal subgroups harder.

Thanks.

Comment: Robinson's introduction to group theory textbook should be good for this. I work with finite groups, but my recollection is that those are distinct in the infinite case and examples are given in the textbook. A reasonable example to keep in mind for nice infinite nilpotent groups are matrix groups, upper triangular with 1s on the diagonal. If you keep the entries as integers you get a polycyclic group (nearly as good as finite), and if you let them vary over a field of char 0 you get fairly well behaved infinitely generated groups. Some not-nice examples are modifications of these

Comment: #2 is called the "normalizer condition" (otherwise it is hard to index or google)